# How to create [youtube]-Tag for PECL bbcode extension?

Tags: php, youtube, bbcode, pecl

I use the [PECL bbcode extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) for parsing BBCode-Tags.

Can anybody show me a way of *replacing* the text between the BBCode tags instead of *surrounding* it with HTML tags? I want to build a `[youtube]` Tag:

```
[youtube]w0ffwDYo00Q[/youtube]
```

My configuration for this tag looks like this:

```
$tags = array(
    'youtube' => array(
        'type'     => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
        'open_tag' => 
            '<object width="425" height="350">
                 <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{CONTENT}"></param>
                 <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{CONTENT}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
             </object>',
        'close_tag' => '',
    ),
);
```

The Problem: the text between the `[youtube]` tags (Youtube ID) is needed twice (for object and embed tags) so I cannot use the `close_tag` as intended.

Result: the markup for inclusion of Youtube player is created correctly but after that the Youtube-ID is printed:

```
<object width="425" height="350">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/w0ffwDYo00Q"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/w0ffwDYo00Q" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>w0ffwDYo00Q
```

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test right now, so not sure it works... But maybe you can try this :

The documentation of [`bbcode_create`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bbcode-create.php) describes the keys/values you can use to configure your tag.

One of these keys is :

> `content_handling` optional - Gives the
> **callback used for modification of the
> content**. Object Oriented Notation
> supported only since 0.10.1 callback
> prototype is string name(string
> $content, string $argument)

So, what if you define that property, so that it is a link to a function modifying the content... Modifying it by setting it to an empty string, for instance ?

Something like this, maybe :

```
$tags = array(
    'youtube' => array(
        'type'     => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
        'open_tag' => 
            '<object width="425" height="350">
                 <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{CONTENT}"></param>
                 <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{CONTENT}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
             </object>',
        'close_tag' => '',
        'content_handling' => 'remove_handler',
    ),
);
```

And declaring the `remove_handler` function this way :

```
function remove_handler($content, $argument) {
  return '';
}
```

Or maybe that way :

```
function remove_handler(& $content, $argument) {
  $content = '';
}
```

With a bit of luck, this might be enough to remove the content ?

---

**EDIT after the comment about my previous proposition**

---

Hi again,

This time, I've tried what I'm suggesting, and it seems to be working **;-)**

First, you can set `''` for both `open_tag` and `close_tag` ; that way, the `content_handling` callback will be responsible for all the work.

Something like this, so :

```
$tags = array(
    'youtube' => array(
        'type'     => BBCODE_TYPE_NOARG,
        'open_tag' => '',
        'close_tag' => '',
        'content_handling' => 'generate_youtube_tag',
    ),
);
```

The callback function would then look like this :

```
function generate_youtube_tag($content, $argument) {
    // TODO some security checks on $content !
    // Here, I've assumed that a youtube id only contains letters and numbers
    // But I don't know it that's always the case
    if (preg_match('/^[\d\w]+$/', $content)) {
        return <<<NEW_CONTENT
<object width="425" height="350">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$content}"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$content}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>
NEW_CONTENT;
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

It actually generates the whole `<object>` tag, including both occurences of the youtube's id.

And if you call it like this :

```
$text = '[youtube]w0ffwDYo00Q[/youtube]';
$bbHandler = bbcode_create($tags);
$output = bbcode_parse($bbHandler, $text);
var_dump($output);
```

You get this output :

```
string '<object width="425" height="350">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/w0ffwDYo00Q"></param>
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/w0ffwDYo00Q" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350"></embed>
</object>' (length=246)
```

Which kinda looks like something that should be ok **;-)**

Actually, if you just ouput it :

```
echo $output;
```

The video is loaded ; it's called *Simon's Cat 'Cat Man do'*, btw **;-)**

Hope this solves your problem better, this time **:-)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The content gets removed, but unfortunately this happens before it's rendered into the HTML ;)

Comment: Just edited my answer, with another proposition, that seems to work, this time ;-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for further investigating :)

I think I'll do it that way.